# Missing client_id parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

**Stage**:

I want to authenticate users in a RubyOnRails application with Facebook credentials.

I am using `omniauth-facebook` gem in Gemfile, but no `devise`:

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

**Config 1**:

I have configured my omniauth initializer (`config/initializers/omniauth.rb):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '123456789098765', '12345678909876543212345678909876'
end
```

but when I request `/auth/facebook`, it responds with:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

**Config 2**:

I have read in other forums that I should pass these parameters as enviroment arguments, so I tried modifing omniauth initializer replacing this line:

```
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
```

and then in terminal I pass this values:

```
$ export FACEBOOK_KEY=123456789098765
$ export FACEBOOK_SECRET=12345678909876543212345678909876
$ rails s
```

but when I request `/auth/facebook` again, it responds with:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, you've probably figured it out but I've just run into the exact same problem. Simply enter `http://localhost:3000` at http://developers.facebook.com/, and then actually access it using localhost and not `http://0.0.0.0:3000` like I was doing.